# Automatically detect by payload if POST, PUT or PATCH is needed

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, protocols

I have a frontend TypeScript app that uses a RESTful api.

I have following domains there:

```
interface Foo {
  id: string;
  prop: string;
  anotherProp: string;
}

interface Bar {
  id: string;
  someProp: string;
  yetAnotherProp: string;
}
```

I also have some endpoints to create / update objects of this domain:

```
POST  - /api/foo
PUT   - /api/foo/{id}

POST  - /api/bar
PATCH - /api/bar/{id}
```

Now I want to detect if I need to call my endpoint with POST, PUT or PATCH.

Since the definition of POST is that I want to create a new object, I don't need an id. So that would be my condition. If my object has no property `id`, I call POST. Easy.

I'm struggling at making a difference for PUT and PATCH though. Since you use PUT if you send the whole object as payload, and use PATCH if you only send parts of the object (e.g. a `Bar` as `{ id: 1, someProp: 'value' }` with `yetAnotherProp` missing), I thought about checking the object to have all available properties to be defined, and call PUT then.

But that would not work in case I want to call a PATCH with all properties changing.

What can I do here to detect what protocol I need in that situation?

Comment: I would just make a service that has all your crud functions. Messing around with automagically figuring out the correct HTTP verb seems kind of pointless (IMO). What would make sense though is having a model with `model.create()`, `model.update()`, `model.delete()`, etc... An example on how to setup something like this would be to check out Mongoose (for mongodb)

Comment: I do it like that for now. But I have a lot of models that all have these calls and it results in a lot of boilerplate code which is what I want to reduce by automating that.